# How can I get groups and users that has been assigned to Sharepoint List using Client Side Script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, csom

How can I get groups and users that has been assigned to Sharepoint List  using Client Side Script.

Please help me to on this

Answer (score 2):

The assigned users and groups to a list can be retrieved using RoleAssignments. Here is a sample code to list them.

**CSOM C# sample**

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listNameTestCL);
var assignments = list.RoleAssignments;
clientContext.Load(assignments, ac => ac.Include(a => a.Member));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var assignmentList = assignments.ToList();
foreach(var assignment in assignmentList)
{
    var strRoleDefinition = "";
    forreach(var roleDefinition in assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
    {
        strRoleDefinition += roleDefinition.Name + ", ";    
    }
    strRoleDefinition = strRoleDefinition.Trim().TrimEnd(',');
    Response.Write(assignment.Member.Title.ToString() + " -- " + assignment.Member.PrincipalType.ToString() + " -- " + strRoleDefinition);
}
```

**JSOM sample**

```
function listAllRoleAssignments(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var webLists = clientContext.get_web().get_lists();
    var list = webLists.getByTitle("TestCL");
    clientContext.load(list);
    var assignments = list.get_roleAssignments();
    clientContext.load(assignments, 'Include(Member,RoleDefinitionBindings)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    function onSuccess(){
        var assignmentsEnumerator =  assignments.getEnumerator();
        while (assignmentsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var assignment = assignmentsEnumerator.get_current();
            var roleDefinitionBindings = assignment.get_roleDefinitionBindings();

            var roleDefinition = getRoleDefinition(roleDefinitionBindings);
            console.log(assignment.get_member().get_title() +  " -- " + getPrincipalTypeName(assignment.get_member().get_principalType()) + " -- " + roleDefinition);
        }
    }
    function onFail(o, args){
        console.log("error: " + args.get_message());
    }

}
function getPrincipalTypeName(principalType){
    switch(principalType){
        case 0:
            return "None";
        case 1:
            return "User";
        case 2:
            return "Distribution List"; 
        case 4:
            return "Security Group";    
        case 8:
            return "SharePoint Group";                  
        default:
            return "All"
    }
}
function getRoleDefinition(roleDefinitionBindings){
    var strRoleDefinition = "";
    for(i=0; i<roleDefinitionBindings.get_count(); i++){
        strRoleDefinition += roleDefinitionBindings.getItemAtIndex(i).get_name() + ", ";
    }
    return strRoleDefinition.substring(0, strRoleDefinition.length - 2);
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(listAllRoleAssignments, "SP.js");
```

Comment: Dear Boss can i have this one code for ecma script this one through the error

Comment: Boss can i have ECMA script above code...

Comment: @sankajayaram I have updated the JSOM sample in the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: You are the great boss .now it is working ..Thank you very much..If any thing i will msg you..

Comment: Boss how can i get Role Defination for the group..any properties

Comment: @sankajayaram, Have added the role definitions - please check the sample code in the answer

Comment: Boss i have done successfully thank you very much for your help..

Comment: Boss would like to ask you one solution ..through client side code i should get particular list granted group name and this group whether granted  or not in site  also ..please help me on this ..looking forward your replay